# How can I swap control and command in bootcamp?

Tags: windows-7, macbook-pro, boot-camp

Didn't see this exact question on here, so figured I'd ask anyway.

It's simple, I do a lot of dev on a macbook pro, and now I'm using a bootcamp a lot as well. My muscle memory has me doing command-x/c/v for control and paste options. So I'd like to find a way to swap those keys in Windows 7. It's not part of a VM, just booting directly in to Windows.

In bootcamp, the command key acts as a windows key, if that's any ehlp.